# Sql exception Login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sqlexception

I have an application and a WCF service which is part of that application.What is happening if I call the service directly it results in following exception :

"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Kanix'.\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\u000a   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\u000a   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\u000a   at DataAccessLayer.SQLHelper.GetMultipleResultSets(String strSQlSPName, Dictionary`2& params, List`1 outParams) in D:\TFS SAAS\HighriseLicensing-\DataAccessLayer\SqlHelper.vb:line 162\u000a   at DataAccessLayer.LoginDL.AuthenticateKey(String key, Int32 guid, String userid, Int32 Mode) in D:\TFS SAAS\HighriseLicensing-\DataAccessLayer\LoginDL.vb:line 20\u000a   at BusinessLogicLayer.LoginBL.AuthenticateKey(String key, Int32 guid, String userid, Int32 Mode) in D:\TFS SAAS\HighriseLicensing-\BusinessLogicLayer\LoginBL.vb:line 18\u000a   at Lincensing.GetFaith.CheckKeyvalidity(String key, Int32 guid, String InstallationId, Int32 Mode) in D:\TFS SAAS\HighriseLicensing-\Lincensing\GetFaith.asmx.vb:line 53\u000a   at Lincensing.GetFaith.CheckKey(String key, Int32 guid, String InstallationId, Int32 Mode) in D:\TFS SAAS\HighriseLicensing-\Lincensing\GetFaith.asmx.vb:line 23\u000a   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"

One important thing is that when I login from the application this service works fine but if i logout from the application its give this error.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are having problem about login. Please connect the server directly from sql server management studio or whatsoever using same credentials. Credentials not valid.